# Stylesheet not being loaded?

Tags: themes, plugins

I placed a link for an extra stylesheet in my header:

```
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/woo.css' type='text/css'/>
```

Which works fine on my local machine, but on my staging server the CSS is not applied. When I view source and follow the link for the stylesheet, it loads just fine, so I know the link is not broken.

But for some reason that stylesheet is not being applied to the page. I checked permissions, they are 644. I am stumped. I've never had this happen before.

Using WooCommerce with Rockwell child theme.

Comment: Thanks everyone for closing this. What a helpful community.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes CSS changes don't load all the time, and it requires you to hard reload the page for it to show up for you. Have your hard reloaded your page in your browser? You could be looking at a cached view. Try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to perform a hard reload.

Comment: First thing I tried, I did clear my browsing cache and reload, no change.